# Check for comma in textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How to check for a comma in a text box? I.e. if comma is present the code should alert,

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
```

Comment: When should the validation occur? When clicking a button? Typing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do like:

```
if ($('#name').val().indexOf(',') !== -1)
{
  alert('There was a comma');
}
```

As you have not specified, you could put that code in `blur` event, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#name").blur(function() { // or keyup, keydown, keypress, whatever you need
    if(this.value.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
        alert('got a comma');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't really need jQuery (for the test). Here's a regular expression `test()`.

```
if( /\,/.test( $('#name').val() ) ) {
   alert('found a comma');
}
```

A regular expression `test()` function returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

And the obligatory no-jQuery solution ;)

```
if (document.getElementById("name").value.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    ....    
}
```